# ANTLR - Trigger after processing one rule

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have this very simple grammar in ANTLR4:

```
 rule : 'SubRelationOf' LPAREN r COMMA r RPAREN
 r:     RN | 'RelationUnionOf' LPAREN (r COMMA)+ r RPAREN

 //LEXER
 RN : [a-z]+ ;
 COMMA: ',';
 LPAREN: '(';
 RPAREN: ')';
```

I'm also using the Listener implementation with the stack to trace every single event, since the grammar is context-free and recursive.
As you can see, the *rule* is made of two arguments: the first *r* and the second *r*.
What I strongly need, is a way to distinguish when I finish to process the first one.
Since the Listener implementation has the following:

```
public void exitRule(Parser.RuleContext ctx) {
// do something
}
```

there is no way to understand when I am in the first r or in the second r of the *rule*.
Is there a trigger that says "ok you are just out of the first r, execute your arbitrary code"?
Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rules where a subrule or token appears more than once you will have a function that returns a list instead of a single entry. So, your `RuleContext` has a member `r()` which returns a list. The order of the entries in it is what you defined in your grammar.